# How many ways can we construct $(a,b,c,d)$ such that $a \geq b, c \geq d$ and $a+b \geq c+d$?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I've been stuck on the counting problem described below for a while. I'm constructing ordered sequences of four positive integers of the form $(a,b,c,d)$, each of which are bounded above. i.e. $$a,b,c,d \in \{1,2,...,N\}$$ so that each of the variables can take on $N$ possible values. Of course, the number of lists we can form this way is $N^4$. Now, I impose that both $a\geq b$ and $c \geq d$. Since these conditions are independent, one can consider the number of ways to construct the first two elements of the list and square it. The number of ways to construct $(a,b)$ such that $a \geq b$ is simply $\frac 12 N(N+1)$, so the answer to this problem is $$\left(\frac 12 N(N+1) \right)^2=\frac 14 N^2(N+1)^2.$$ Now, where I'm getting stuck is the addition of a third constraint. This is to require that $a+b \geq c+d$, thus making the first two and last two components dependent on each other. My question is therefore: How many ordered lists of the form $(a,b,c,d)$ such that $$a,b,c,d \in \{1,2,...,N\}$$
$$a \geq b, \qquad c\geq d$$
$$a+b \geq c+d$$ are there?

Comment: Hint: For the $N^2(N+1)^2/4$ quadruplets $(a,b,c,d)$ satisfying the first two constraints, there are three cases: $a+b>c+d$, $a+b<c+d$, and $a+b=c+d$. What can you say about the number of quadruplets in each of them, and can you maybe calculate any of them?

Comment: The cases $a+b>c+d$ and $a+b<c+d$ have the same number of solutions, so the only case you have to solve is $a+b = c+d$. It is work though...
For the final problem $a+b \geq c+d$ I find $F(N)$ solutions when $N$ is even, and $F(N)+1/8$ cases when $N$ is odd, where $F(N) = N(N+2)(3N^2+2N+2)/24$.

Comment: Mark's answer for even N is correct but I can't make sense out of his comment concerning the odd case.  I have a solution for the odd case written using math type but don't know how to post it.

Comment: @judithKhan use LaTex guide to know how to add mathematical symbols.

Comment: Note that if you don't need an _exact_ number, it's straightforward to extract a first-order approximation $N^4/8+O(N^3)$ from the continuous case: The total number of points $\langle a,b,c,d\rangle$ is $N^4$ and each of the three constraints divides the (remaining) space 'in half' up to an $O(N^3)$ factor.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the previous analysis.  We know that the number of ways
$a+b > c+d$ equals the number of ways $a+b < c+d$.  We find the number
of ways $a+b = c+d$, calling it $f(n)$.  Then the answer to the
problem is
 $$ \frac{\displaystyle\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}-f(n)}{2} + f(n)
  = \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{8} + \frac{f(n)}{2}.$$
The value of $f(n)$ depends upon the parity of $n$.  If $n$ is even,
  $$ f_e(n) = \frac{n(2n^2+3n+4)}{12}. $$
If $n$ is odd,
  $$ f_o(n) = \frac{(n+1)(2n^2+n+3)}{12}. $$
The function for odd and even $n$ were reached by establishing a
pattern using numbers and then using induction.